# Is it possible to override a local module's type declarations?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm trying to override what a particular typescript module looks like to anyone that's importing it.

This is because I have some webpack rules that actually change what the exports of this module are at transpile time.

I have a custom module declaration in a `custom.d.ts` file:

```
declare module '*.worker' {
  class WebpackWorker extends Worker {
    constructor();
  }

  export default WebpackWorker;
}
```

And then I import this module as

```
import MyWorker from './test.worker';

const worker = new MyWorker();
```

However, I can't seem to get the custom module declaration to recognise that it is of the types declared in my custom.d.ts file. Does anyone know if overriding a local module's exported types is possible?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to say say FileA.ts has an export called Human and at webpack compile time that Human gets it's name changed to Animal is to add declare type into that class and import that something like...

```
export class Human {
    bark() {
        return "bark bark"
    }
}
export declare class Animal extends Human {};
```

then in FileB.ts you can import Animal and use it with type safety.